# Optimize TeamViewer for android bandwidth consumption

Tags: remote-access, vnc, teamviewer

I am using TeamViewer for Android to remotely control my computer and it works great, but I recently noticed it uses up a LOT of bandwidth, even in Optimize Speed mode. I have a limited 3G plan and I would like to reduce TeamViewer's bandwidth consumption as much as possible, at the expense of image quality. For example, I would have no problem with going to grayscale, or 256-color mode, but this option is not available on the android client, as far as I can tell.

Is there any way to optimize the bandwidth consumption of TeamViewer for Android, beyond choosing the Optimize Speed quality setting? If not, is there any other remote desktop client for android that you can recommend which does a better job that TeamViewer in this category?

Thanks

Comment: Give [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.chromeremotedesktop&hl=en) this a try. The recent version claims "Reduced network usage when running in the background."

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP has no account on this site, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I use Teamviewer and love it.  Before Teamviewer I used several of the pocket VNC versions you can find for Android.  Some of those version have grayscale options.  The drawback is you will have to forward a port on your router to get VNC to go through.  The other option you may look at is if the program or programs you are looking to control have a web API you can hit rather then the whole PC.  below are some links for the other programs to control your PC via ANDROID.

EDIT: thought about it a little more and remembered you can use LogMeIn Hamachi and VNC.  Set up the LogMeIn Hamachi client on the PC you want to connect to, then you can VNC into the Virtual IP the Hamachi client provides.  This will enable you to use the advanced display setting in some of the VNC clients.  [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/)

- [Android Remotes](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-apps-remote-access-rdp-vnc-remote-desktop-82521/)
- [More Remotes](http://slodive.com/freebies/android-remote-desktop-apps/)
- [Some more](http://gizmodo.com/5966724/how-to-control-your-computer-with-your-phone)

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention in the first post: port forwarding is not an option for me, so it has to be a software that supports NAT bypass

Comment: Teamviewer is your best option, followed by LogMeIn.  I have also used the LogMeIn product and it works well.  Teamviewer has a better interface and ran cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Note that the free LogMeIn Hamachi service has been 'discontinued' http://community.logmein.com/t5/LogMeIn-for-iOS/Free-Service-Discontinued/td-p/108649